# Как найти драйвера на старое оборудование?

Tags: драйвер

Есть старый необычный принтер, который использует векторную графику. Он старый (~2004 года), в рабочей состоянии, но при подключении к компу - пишет, что дрова не установлены, как мне можно их найти, если через автоматическое обновление драйверов - он не находит? Утилита какая-нибудь или проще будет самому эти дрова написать?))[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

1. 80% плоттеров используют векторную графику (даже сейчас в 2021г), храниться они в PLT
2. Забавно, но мой Kyocera Mita FS-800 так-же дохлый принтер, работает через VirtualBox через 100% симуляцию LPT порта.

Ответ на твой вопрос... Если физический подключил плоттер, то деревянные дрова к нему можно поставить в VBox с перераспределением железных адресов, от туда уже в сеть выводишь плоттер.

Comment: Не сработало, он пытался найти в нём драйвера, но не получается и предлагаем диск с дровами вставить, а у меня их нет, есть какой-нибудь ещё вариант?

Comment: @НикитаБородинов  https://ibb.co/g9HHW6r    Перенаправляешь порт, прописываешь на хосте его через \\.\DEVICE и для Guest прописываешь его как IRQ + IO Port. Вместо диска с дровами, можно в ручную найти устройство по его Hardware Id's https://supportkb.dell.com/img/ka02R000000kpZgQAI/ka02R000000kpZgQAI_en_US_1.jpeg